# BHO, IHTMLDocument2:get_scripts() and external script

Tags: windows, com, sdk, bho

I am writing a BHO, the code using IHTMLDocument2::get_scripts to get all script body in the 
HTML file then use get_text() to get script source. But I found if script is embedded from a external file, the content is 
an empty string.

Is there any way to get source code from an IHTMLScriptElement that is 
created by ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IHTMLScriptElement::src to get the url of the script, then dig the WinInet cache. if it is not cached, download again.

Comment: This seems a reasonable solution. I forget dig the cache file. Thanks.